# Hide/Show part of the form on click. How to debug?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning JS/Jquery and I'm trying to make a part of a form show and hide when clicking on part of the form. I am able to open part of the form, but not to close it again.

As there is no error showing in the console. I was wondering how people would go about debugging this type of bug?

The form:

```
<div class="col col-sm-4 more-options">Detailed options</div>

<div class="row advanced-options">
  #part of the form to open and close
</div>
```

The JS/jQuery code:

```
$(".more-options").click(function(){
    if ('.advanced-options:hidden') {
        $('.advanced-options').show();
    } else {
        $('.advanced-options').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: The other answers are correct. For this type of functionality you can also use the toggle method or the slideToggle method: `$('.advanced-options').toggle();`
Take a look to the documentation :[https://api.jquery.com/toggle/](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you have in your code is basically every single time truthy value for your `if` statement.

Imagine the following scenario:

```js
if ('.advanced-options:hidden') {
  console.log(`I'm true`);
} else {
  console.log(`I won't be showed up anywhere`);
}
```

Technically `string` is evaluated as `true` value and that's causing your issue in the code.

I guess the solution is the following:

```
$(".more-options").click(function(){
  if ($('.advanced-options').is(':hidden')) {
    $('.advanced-options').show();
  } else {
    $('.advanced-options').hide();
  }
});
```

On other cases, you can use [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) step where you are not sure what values you have in your code for further debugging.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have change some code:

I have added on "$" sign in if condition, and in condition i have checked length of element. And this is not stupid thing just your beginning, so enjoy the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="col col-sm-4 more-options">Detailed options</div>
      <div class="row advanced-options">
         #part of the form to open and close
      </div>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".more-options").click(function(){

             if ($('.advanced-options:hidden').length > 0) {
               $('.advanced-options').show();
             } else {
               $('.advanced-options').hide();
             }
           });
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The part `if ('.advanced-options:hidden')` due to the condition is a string which gets interpreted as `true`. Did you mean `if ($('.advanced-options:hidden'))` ?

Comment: Thanks, and yes I did;)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your actual question: I would use the javascript function `console.log()` to provide myself with logging output.

In your case for example:

```
$(".more-options").click(function(){
    console.log('clicked!');
    if ('.advanced-options:hidden') {
      console.log('reached the first condition);
      $('.advanced-options').show();
    } else {
      console.log('else was called');
      $('.advanced-options').hide();
    }
  });
```

And in the concrete example, you just have a string in your if-clause, which would always evaluate to true. You are probably meaning to do something like `$('.advanced-options:hidden')`, but that's quite inefficient. In this case you would want to get the element in question and then check its properties.

Comment: Thanks for the help and elaborate response.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the **.toggle()** method of JQuery to open and close your div.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col col-sm-4 more-options" style="display:none">Detailed options</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(".more-options").click(function(){
    $('.advanced-options').toggle();
}
```

This is how you can reduce the line of code and make it look good.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this is indeed a very elegant solution and it works.